# Unchanged files showing in Git pull request

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github

We are currently using Git (Visual Studio) in a 5 man team.  This is the process we currently follow:

1. User creates a feature branch from master before they start work
2. They implement their feature
3. When the implementation is complete they do a merge from master to their feature branch (and resolve any conflicts) so they have the latest changes in their feature branch
4. A pull request is created for someone to review, if everything is ok then the feature branch is merged into master

The issue we have is that the pull request shows changes that were not part of the feature. So if DeveloperA completed a feature while DeveloperB was still working then when DeveloperB creates a pull request it will contain DeveloperA's files (because of step 3)

This is slightly annoying because the reviewer not only sees DeveloperB's changes but also DeveloperA's.  Are there any better processes that we can follow?

Comment: Our team also has this problem.  Even though everyone has the same autocrlf settings, it seems like something silently changes line endings.  So it claims whitespace changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommend each developer should have their own feature branch and should only update from the master branch only. By doing this developer will only have changes that are specific to a feature branch and should not pull changes from other feature branches.

1. Create feature branch from master
2. DevA makes changes to feature branch
3. DevB makes changes to their own feature branch
4. DevA sends pull request to merge to master
5. DevA changes are merged into master
6. DevB must now update their feature branch with master
7. DevB sends pull request to master

Does that help at all

Comment: This is what we have. When DevB sends a pull request it shows DevA changes (because of step 6).  The compare shows no changes to these files but it would be good to exclude them from the pull request.

Comment: Since DevA changes are now merged into master, if DevB updates their branch with the new master and then sends a pull request. At that point the only change between master and DevB feature branch should be the only changes done in DevB feature branch. I suspect why you are seeing DevA changes when DevB sends a pull request is because the changes in DevA have not yet being merged into master but they must have been pulled or merged into the DevB feature branch instead